# Which languages are available in Live DVD version?

Tags: language-support

If there is no internet connection, which language else I could choose to use Ubuntu localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many languages are available on a DVD edition (not CD) of Ubuntu. You have to check the manifest of the version you want.

For example, for Ubuntu 12.04.2 64bit, the manifest is [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.2/release/ubuntu-12.04.2-dvd-amd64.manifest).

When you open the page, click the search button of your browser (Firefox=F3) and write:**language-pack**, then click on **Highlight all** and you will see which languages are available on the DVD.

[image]

[Page with all available Ubuntu releases.](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/)